# How to check current user against post ID to delete

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I have a `deletePost` function that will delete a post but currently, any user can delete any other user's posts.

I added a check but now the user can't delete their own or anyone else's posts.

```
  Future<void> deletePost(String postId) async {
    try {
      if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid == _firestore.collection('posts').doc('uid').toString()) {
        await _firestore.collection('posts').doc(postId).delete();
      }
    } catch (err) {
      print(err.toString());
    }
  }
```

I want to be able to do a check to see if the `currentUser`'s `uid` is the `post` user's `uid` and then delete else for it to do nothing.

Rules added:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  match /users/{userId}/{document=**} {
    allow read, write;
    delete: if request.auth.uid == userId 
      }
      }
    }
```

I now receive `[Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(posts/*******-****-****-*******/comments order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}` when accessing the `posts feed.`
Assuming I've messed up the rules for testing.

Solution:

```
InkWell(
                              onTap: () async {
                                if (FirebaseAuth
                                        .instance.currentUser!.uid == widget.snap['uid']) {
                                  FirestoreMethods().deletePost(
                                    widget.snap['postId'],
                                  );
                                  Navigator.of(context).pop(context);
                                }
                              },
```

Rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  match /users/{userId}/{document=**} {
    allow delete: if request.auth.uid == userId 
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is Firestore rule's job, not a front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set up some rules for this check on the firestore side:

**The first case: You have to put your posts collection inside users collection in this case this rule will work**

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    
  match /users/{userId}/{document=**} {
  allow delete: if request.auth.uid == userId
  }  
  }
}
```

**The second case: If your posts and users are separate collections, in this case, you can configure this rule for security purposes:**

```
match /posts/{document=**} {
    allow read, delete, create: if request.auth != null
    }
```

In post collection, you have to place a parameter which is called `userId`. But in your UI, you have to put a check which will check whether this post belongs to the user.

[image]

```
postDocs[index]['userId'] == futureSnapshot.data.uid
```

Comment: I've updated my question. Thanks for the response. I'm confused as to why I'm receiving `Permission`errors now

Comment: is your posts collections located inside users collection?

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can look at it

Comment: No, posts and users are separate collections

Comment: Is there no way to do it with separate collections?

Comment: In this case, you cannot pass userId parameter to check for (this post belongs to this user or not). In your case, you have to place userId parameter to your posts collections, you have to check it in your app logic (if (currentUserId == post[id])

Comment: `if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid == _firestore.collection('posts').doc('uid').toString())` Does this logic not check for that?

Comment: Can you check my answer, I updated it

Comment: No, as I just said you have to put userId parameter as a field inside your posts collection.

Comment: I did have a user `uid` in the `posts` collection but was unsure how to access it. Following your examples helped me get to the solution above.